# How to join tables, concatenate some data

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables:
1. indexes and quantity of indexes
2. indexes and quantity of indexes with specified boxcodes. Boxcode is a number of box, which box contains indexes.

```
1. input table 1

item_id quantity
1       10
2       15
3       5
1       5
1       5
2       5
3       5

sum:
1 - 20
2 - 20
3 - 10



2. input table 2

item_id quantity    boxcode
1       3           abc
2       2           abc
1       8           def
3       10          ghi
1       9           ghi
2       9           def
2       8           ghi             !!!!!!!

1 item_id once on 1 boxcode
```

I want to get result:

```
3. result

    item_id quantity    boxcodes
    1       10          abc/3, def/7
    2       15          abc/2, def/9, ghi/4
    3       5           ghi/5
    1       5           def/1, ghi/4
    1       5           ghi/5
    2       5           ghi/4                       !!!!!!!!
    3       5           ghi/5
```

Records from table 1 must be in the same order.
I have no idea how it can be done.
Any suggestion?

```
CREATE TABLE #input1
(
    rownum int,
    item_id int,
    quantity int
)

CREATE TABLE #input2
(
    item_id int,
    quantity int,
    boxcode varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO #input1 VALUES (1,1,10)
INSERT INTO #input1 VALUES (2,2,15)
INSERT INTO #input1 VALUES (3,3,5)
INSERT INTO #input1 VALUES (4,1,5)
INSERT INTO #input1 VALUES (5,1,5)
INSERT INTO #input1 VALUES (6,2,5)
INSERT INTO #input1 VALUES (7,3,5)

INSERT INTO #input2 VALUES (1,3, 'abc')
INSERT INTO #input2 VALUES (2,2, 'abc')
INSERT INTO #input2 VALUES (1,8, 'def')
INSERT INTO #input2 VALUES (3,10, 'ghi')
INSERT INTO #input2 VALUES (1,9, 'ghi')
INSERT INTO #input2 VALUES (2,9, 'def')
INSERT INTO #input2 VALUES (2,8, 'ghi')

select * from #input1
select * from #input2

drop table #input1
drop table #input2
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GRF7.jpg)

Thanks,

Comment: You dont have table names or anything so its hard to write answer, but try to u se ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY item_id) on the first table

Comment: how you get abc/3..def/7

Comment: Records from table 1 must be in the same order.
I get first record from input_table_1, and find boxcodes with item_id1 (input_table_2). I need quantity: 10. I get 3 from 'abc' box and 7 from 'def' box.
3 + 7 = 10

Comment: you need a pure SQL solution? what have you tried?

Comment: @peter . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "same order" between two tables, unless a column represents the ordering.  I see no such column in your data.

Comment: I did not say precisely. I add some code. input1 contains column rownum, I'd like the same order by this column in result.

Comment: I'm not sure I need pure SQL solution. I'll try do this with cursor, the only way I think I can do it. Maybe there is another way to do this.

Comment: But you don't have any `rownum` for `#input2`...

Comment: Yes and I will not have such information. I need to match quantities from boxes. It's like empting boxes (from input2) from top to bottom throught input1 records.

Comment: I got it (I hope)! Take a look on my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Weird, but it works:

```
;WITH rec1 AS (
    SELECT  rownum,
            item_id,
            1 as q,
            1 as [Level],
            quantity
    from #input1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  r.rownum,
            r.item_id,
            1,
            [Level] + 1,
            i.quantity
    FROM rec1 r
    INNER JOIN #input1 i
        ON r.rownum = i.rownum AND r.item_id = i.item_id
    WHERE [Level] < i.quantity
), rec2 AS (
    SELECT  boxcode,
            item_id,
            1 as q,
            1 as [Level],
            quantity
    from #input2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  r.boxcode,
            r.item_id,
            1,
            [Level] + 1,
            i.quantity
    FROM rec2 r
    INNER JOIN #input2 i
        ON r.boxcode = i.boxcode AND r.item_id = i.item_id
    WHERE [Level] < i.quantity
), cte1 AS (
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY item_id, rownum) as rn
    FROM rec1
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY item_id, boxcode) as rn
    FROM rec2
), final AS (
    SELECT  c1.rownum,
            c1.item_id,
            c1.quantity,
            c2.boxcode+'/'+CAST(SUM(c2.q) as nvarchar(10)) as boxcodes
    FROM cte1 c1
    INNER JOIN cte2 c2
        ON c1.item_id = c2.item_id and c1.rn = c2.rn
    GROUP BY c1.rownum, c1.item_id, c1.quantity, c2.boxcode
)

SELECT DISTINCT 
                f.rownum,
                f.item_id,
                f.quantity,
                STUFF((
                    SELECT ', '+f1.boxcodes
                    FROM final f1
                    WHERE f1.rownum = f.rownum 
                        AND f1.item_id = f.item_id 
                        AND f1.quantity = f.quantity
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ),1,2,'') boxcodes
FROM final f
```

Output for dataset you have provided:

```
rownum  item_id quantity    boxcodes
1       1       10          abc/3, def/7
2       2       15          abc/2, def/9, ghi/4
3       3       5           ghi/5
4       1       5           def/1, ghi/4
5       1       5           ghi/5
6       2       5           ghi/4
7       3       5           ghi/5
```

The main idea is to spread quantity in both tables for a small parts `1`. Than add row number, then join and get result.

Answer (score 1):

A solution (but it's totally based on gofr1's answer, to be honest !), to simplify a bit, would be to create a Numbers table, with as many numbers as you want.

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers(Number INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT Numbers 
SELECT TOP 1000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
FROM sys.all_columns;
```

That would just avoid the 2 recursive CTEs.

You could then use the same logic as gofr1 :

```
with rec1 AS (
    SELECT  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY item_id, rownum) as rn,
            rownum,
            item_id,
            case when quantity = 0 then 0 else 1 end as q,
            quantity
    from #input1
    join Numbers n on n.Number <= quantity
)

, rec2 AS (
    SELECT  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY item_id, boxcode) as rn,
            boxcode,
            item_id,
            case when quantity = 0 then 0 else 1 end as q,
            quantity
    from #input2
   join Numbers n on n.Number <= quantity
),

 final AS (
    SELECT  c1.rownum,
            c1.item_id,
            c1.quantity,
            c2.boxcode+'/'+CAST(SUM(c2.q) as nvarchar(10)) as boxcodes
    FROM rec1 c1
    INNER JOIN rec2 c2
        ON c1.item_id = c2.item_id and c1.rn = c2.rn
    GROUP BY c1.rownum, c1.item_id, c1.quantity, c2.boxcode
),
stuffed as (
SELECT   
       distinct rownum,       
       f.item_id,
       f.quantity,
       STUFF((
           SELECT ', '+f1.boxcodes
           FROM final f1
           WHERE f1.rownum = f.rownum 
                 AND f1.item_id = f.item_id 
                 AND f1.quantity = f.quantity
           FOR XML PATH('')
       ),1,2,'') boxcodes
FROM final f
group by item_id, quantity, boxcodes, rownum)

select * 
from stuffed
order by rownum
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my answer! Just a note: OP added rownum to his question, see the part of creation script.